Spring @Transactional on derived method when autowiring through interface
Would the bean.method() call respect @Transactional annotation given following code?
public interface Iface {
    void method();
}

@Component
public class Derived implements Iface {
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void method() {
        // some logic
    }
}

@Component
public class SomeComponent {

    @Autowired
    private Iface bean;

    public void someCall() {
        bean.method();
    }
}


Yes. Transaction should open. Also you could check it for example via enabling transaction logs logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG or calling TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() inside method.

Simple answer: Yes, the bean.method() call will respect @Transactional annotation. A transaction will be created and do its job while doing the Data Access Layer Operations.
